# How to remove ?callback.. form url in next-auth redirect

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am using next-auth and when the user is not logged in is viewing the protected route it should redirect the user to localhost:3000/login but it redirects to http://localhost:3000/login?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fdashboard

How to remove that ?callbackUrl..

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import { db } from "@/lib/prismadb";
import { getUserById } from "@/actions/user";
import { User, UserRole } from "@prisma/client";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(db),

  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "email" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password) {
          return null;
        }

        const user = await db.user.findUnique({
          where: { email: credentials.email },
        });

        if (!user) {
          return null;
        }

        const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(
          credentials.password,
          user.password,
        );

        if (!passwordMatch) {
          return null;
        }

        return user;
      },
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },

  callbacks: {
    async session({ token, session }) {
      if (token.sub && session.user) {
        session.user.id = token.sub;
      }

      if (token.role && session.user) {
        session.user.role = token.role as UserRole;
      }

      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token }) {
      if (!token.sub) return token;

      const existingUser = (await getUserById(token.sub)) as User;

      if (!existingUser) return token;

      token.role = existingUser.role;

      return token;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

-----> And Yes I have write this in .env file  also
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000

Answer (score 0):

I think the brutal approach would be deleting the param if it were in the URL in the `redirect` callback of your `auth.js` / `auth.ts`, something along these lines:

```
callbacks: {
    async redirect(props) {
        const { baseUrl } = props;
        let { url } = props;
        const cleanedUpUrl = new URL(url);
        cleanedUpUrl.searchParams.delete("callbackUrl");
        url = cleanedUpUrl.toString();
        // Allows relative callback URLs
        if (url.startsWith("/")) return `${baseUrl}${url}`
        // Allows callback URLs on the same origin
        else if (new URL(url).origin === baseUrl) return url
        return baseUrl
    }
}
```

[Take the doc into account](https://authjs.dev/guides/basics/callbacks#redirect-callback) and the default value of it.